# Symfony2 No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

After creating entity with:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

and while using:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I encountered:

> No Metadata Classes to process.

**Entity**

```
namespace ISLab\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu_items")
 */
class MenuItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent", type="integer")
     */
    private $parent;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: Please provide code where this error occurs.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and took me a while until I find out how to clear out the cache. Clearing only doctrine's cache did not work for me. Use the command below to clear the entire environment (production one in this case)

`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you. This worked for me like charm

Comment: Had this issue with Symfony 3.1, and this answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when I generate an Entity through the interactive generator from command line. When I first created I set the Configuration Format to **PHP** and that didn't work. So I deleted it and tried again but this time I selected **format = annotation**. Then it worked! Maybe this could solve someone's problem.

Comment: Fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 5):

So entity manager didn't create metadata for your entity. Here are things I would check first:

1. Clear your cache
2. Make sure your `AdminBundle` is registered in AppKernel.
3. Make sure that entity manager's automapping is `true`. Or set it up correctly if you're using custom EM.

A bit offtopic:

I see you're making a menu system and I would strongly suggest you to check out [Doctrine Extensions Tree](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) which should allow you to query and edit items much more efficiently than with your structure.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when i update the database.
So i follow this solution and i tried to adapt in my case and it works.
I think that is a problem of automapping indeed also with auto_mapping setted  true, symfony wasn't able to find the entities.
I hope that it can help.

```
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        AppBundle:
            type: annotation
            is_bundle: false
            dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Entity/
            prefix: AppBundle\Entity
            alias: AppBundle
```

Comment: Fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

for anyone on the same thing, these are few steps to go:

## 1. Clear the cache:

```
bin/console c:c --env=dev
bin/console c:c --env=prod
```

If you see any errors meanwhile, try to cover it by inspecting source of problem.

## 2. Inspect your configuration:

According to this sample directory structure:

```
Application
|
└- src
   |
   └- Acme
      |
      └- Bundle
         |
         └- BlogBundle
            |
            └- Model
               |
               └- Entity
```

You should have this configuration inside your `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
doctrine:

    ...

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            AcmeBlogBundle:
                mapping: true
                type: annotation
                dir: Model/Entity
                alias: Blog
                prefix: Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle\Model\Entity
                is_bundle: true
```

## 3. Update your database schema:

You can now update your database schema without any problems:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update
```

despite of this being the final step for most cases, you may still use `--verbose` to find any further possible problems.

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your entities are placed in your bundle's `Entity` directory. In my case they were in `Entities` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me generating all the entities from the cmd did the work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i solve the problem creating the **Entity** folder. For some reason it had been eliminated. I hope that it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. For me it was that my directory called 'Entity' was not in the 'AppBundle' but in the 'src' directory. Moving the 'Entity' directory into the 'AppBundle' directory fixed the problem for me!