# Symfony3 Generate Entites from DB

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

New to Symfony... Trying to create Entities from an existing DB. I am attempting to following the instructions at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Long story short it seems that I simply need 3 commands:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
$ php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
$ php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

Note: I Modified the name of the bundle from AcmeBlogBundle to AppBundle because I am just using the default bundle. I also am using Symfony 3, everything I look up online seems to reference symfony2

Anyway, first command seems to run fine. I get orm.xml files generated in my ./src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/ path
Commands 2 and 3 seem to be where my troubles begin.

Command 2 results in

`No Metadata Classes to process`

Command 3 results in (obviously command 2 didnt work correctly but tried anyway)

`[RuntimeException] Bundle "AppBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.`

I'm at a loss here.

Contents of config.yml are:

```yaml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }  
    - { resource: security.yml }  
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

## Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration

```
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~  
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }  
    secret:          "%secret%"  
    router:  
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"  
        strict_requirements: ~  
    form:            ~  
    csrf_protection: ~  
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }  
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }  
    templating:  
        engines: ['twig']  
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme  
    default_locale:  "%locale%"  
    trusted_hosts:   ~  
    trusted_proxies: ~  
    session:  
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini  
        handler_id:  ~  
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"  
    fragments:       ~  
    http_method_override: true  
    assets: ~
```

## Twig Configuration

```
twig:  
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"  
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
```

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:  
    dbal:  
        driver:   pdo_mysql  
        host:     "%database_host%"  
        port:     "%database_port%"  
        dbname:   "%database_name%"  
        user:     "%database_user%"  
        password: "%database_password%"  
        charset:  UTF8  
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:  
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml  
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"  
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist  
        #   3. Uncomment next line:  
        #     path:     "%database_path%"  

    orm:  
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"  
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore  
        auto_mapping: true
```

## Swiftmailer Configuration

```
swiftmailer:  
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"  
    host:      "%mailer_host%"  
    username:  "%mailer_user%"  
    password:  "%mailer_password%"  
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I did end up getting past this by adding i think the "--from database" flag in one of the commands above. I think the second command. I'm pretty sure youre correct that my config is not expecting the xml files so thats why it cant find them.

Comment: Can you post the Doctrine configuration from your `app/config.yml` file? Most likely you just haven't told it to expect the XML files that you generated, so it doesn't know about the entities.

Comment: After command one did you clear the cache?  php app/console cache:clear --env=prod

I do know that if there's some .yml files from other attempts in the doctrine folder this is one cause, having encountered that myself.

Also, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267998/symfony2-no-metadata-classes-to-process

Answer (score 2):

you can run the following command straightaway after configuring your parameters.yml.

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle annotation`

then you can run this command to generate entities

`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`

It's also important to try your database connection before running any of those commands. Try to fetch values with

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM your_table_name"
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very useful. The first command worked like a charm, but in my own case, `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` threw the following exception: _Bundle "AppBundle" does not contain any mapped entities._ I had to clear my cache for that to work: **`$ php bin/console cache:clear`**. Thanks again.