# Issue executing doctrine schema update

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I tried to update my database with the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

but I got the error:

> "No Metadata classes to process"

Comment: this means you either have namespace issues, or are missing ORM certain annotations .., atleast post your entity

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267998/symfony2-no-metadata-classes-to-process) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and took me a while until I find out how to clear out the cache: Try this:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```